MySQL 1142 error, except it's blank for the user name: SELECT command denied to user ''@'%' for table `tablename'
What does this mean when the user name is blank with this typical error:
SELECT command denied to user ''@'%' for table `tablename'
Why doesn't it specify the username that's currently logged in?

how did you connect?

I connect via username/pw. Previously if I tried to execute a certain function, I'd get an error like above except it would specify "username@'%'...

You have tagged both MySQL and MariaDB. Which one are you using? Query SELECT VERSION(); to confirm.

My bad, I'm on MariaDB 10.5.23

This usually happens if you created a user with an empty username:
$> mysql -unonexisting -e"select * from test.t1";
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'nonexisting'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

$> mysql -uroot -e"CREATE USER ''@'%'"

$> mysql -unonexisting -e"select * from test.t1";
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 1: SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table `test`.`t1`

So just drop the user with empty user name.
See also CONJ-432

These steps should help in diagnosing and correcting the issue leading to the error you described.

Check Connection String: Ensure that the connection string in your application includes a username. This is often set in a configuration file or passed as an environment variable.
Review MySQL User Accounts: Check the user accounts configured in your MySQL database, particularly for any anonymous accounts (''). You can review and manage these using commands like SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user; in the MySQL shell.
Grant Permissions: If the correct user is supposed to have access but doesn’t, you might need to grant the necessary permissions using a command like GRANT SELECT ON databasename.tablename TO 'username'@'host';.
Audit and Remove Anonymous Accounts: If there are anonymous accounts and they are not required (or pose a security risk), consider removing them or restricting their access further.
Verify Application Configuration: Double-check that your application is correctly configured to use the appropriate database credentials.

